# Compiling LaTeX via an on-line server

Tags: latex, pdflatex, pdftex

I have a LaTeX text document that compiles fine with the current version of pdflatex on my home computer.  I've made minor edits to the body of the document.  I'm trying to recompile it, using either http://sciencesoft.at/latex/?lang=en or the first google result for the words "latex to pdf online."  (I can't post the hyperlink due to spam prevention.)  The former site is running pdfTeXt; the latter, MikTeX.  I've pasted my headers below.  Does anyone know how I might change them to make either one work?

Thanks,

-- Mark

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}

\pdfpageheight 11in

\pdfpagewidth 8.5in

\doublespacing

\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\headheight{15pt}

\fancyhead[R]{My name}

\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\section*{Finite Simple Groups}

...text...

\end{document}

Comment: Not programming related.

Comment: No, it is -- the central question is how to change LaTeX source so that pdfTeXt (or MikTex) accepts it.

Comment: i'm not really sure, but pdfTeXt sounds like something conTeXt would use.

Comment: you may also want to check out http://monkeytex.bradcater.webfactional.com/

Comment: @Mica: Context is invoked using `context` or `texexec`, and modern versions normally use Luatex as their backend, though Context MkII can be compiled on any web2c tex.

Comment: @Charles I would assume the above to be a typo of "pdfTeX" then :P

Comment: Check out ScribTeX CLSI, it works for me http://clsi.scribtex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the output, I saw the problem was with the `\headheight` command. Googling for that suggests you should change it to `\setlength\headheight{15pt}`. This makes it work with the sciencesoft tool!